# Why does my mouse stop working a short time into my session?

Tags: mouse, troubleshooting

Running Easy Peasy 1.6 clean installation. Hardware - EEE PC 900-HA.

About 10 or so minutes into a new session after a reboot my mouse will stop working. It will still move the pointer, but it will no longer register clicks correctly. The behavior is very strange.

For instance I can be clicking in either a firefox window or on the tab bar. If I clear the cache it will allow me to switch.

Often if there are multiple windows open clicking will only switch between the windows and will not register the click in either window.

The behavior is incredibly erratic. I have tried a clean installation of Easy Peasy 1.6 and also attempted to reinstall input-attach.

UPDATE: my clean installation ran through a bunch of updates last night and the mouse worked for a while, but still started to stop working after 30-60 minutes. I tried letting it sit after logging on and it still just worked for a few minutes and then stopped. Any ideas, thinking about switching flavors if I can't figure it out soon.

Update 2:

When it works:

```
KeymapNotify event, serial 31, synthetic NO, window 0x0,
     keys:  11  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   
            0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   

ButtonPress event, serial 31, synthetic NO, window 0x3e00001,
     root 0x10b, subw 0x0, time 55427, (263,134), root:(263,158),
     state 0x0, button 1, same_screen YES

ButtonRelease event, serial 31, synthetic NO, window 0x3e00001,
     root 0x10b, subw 0x0, time 55531, (263,134), root:(263,158),
     state 0x100, button 1, same_screen YES
```

When it doesn't:

[image: no alt-tab]

Sorry for the image, but alt-tab seems to break too. Pretty sure the keypress event is when I clicked into the window, but I'm not sure of it. If that isn't enough I can try it again and try to get it to copy, can't seem to get the edit menu to open when it's acting up.

Comment: By "mouse", do you mean the built-in touchpad, or have you connected an external mouse to your system?

Comment: @cjm - same behavior with both the touch pad and an external wireless USB mouse. as well as a wired USB mouse.

Comment: Does it stop working sooner based on the amount of mouse movement? Like, if you leave it running for 10 minutes before moving the mouse, does it still freeze?

Comment: @amphetamachine - I think that if I leave it and bring it up a few minutes later the mouse still works for a short period of time. The login screen seems hesitant to come up after sleep as well. Not sure if its related. I will confirm this when I get home later today.

Comment: Run the program `xev` from a terminal. At the beginning of the session, while the mouse is still working, move the mouse into the `xev` window and click in it. Copy-paste the output resulting from your click (a `ButtonPress` event and a `ButtonRelease` event) to a file. Later, when the mouse isn't working, repeat the experiment. Add both reports from `xev` to your question.

Comment: @Gilles - updated. Let me know if you need more information.

Comment: @wax eagle: Have you tried running a live cd (or even a different installation or OS) on this machine? It would help to isolate whether it is a software or hardware issue.

Comment: @Faheem - I ran a live usbkey version of easy peasy into the clean install. During the install process the mouse froze. i will check with a different flavor live tonight and see if anything is different

Comment: @wax eagle: I'd try something that is not the distribution you are running. Eg Debian or Ubuntu if available. Debian for preference.

Comment: @Faheem will give it a shot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `xev` output shows a `KeyPress` event for the `Alt_L` key with `state 0x400`. The state indicates which key modifiers and mouse buttons are down immediately before the event, e.g. `state 0x1` would indicate that `Shift` was down, `state 0x4` that `Control` was down, etc. `state 0x400` indicates that `Button3` (the right mouse button) is down.

What's happening is that your system thinks you're still holding the right mouse button down. This prevents a lot of keyboard and mouse shortcuts from working.

When the problem occurs, try clicking the right mouse button. If what is causing the events to be dropped is sporadic, this will send a `ButtonRelease` event and all will be well again, until the next dropped event.

At this point I don't know what could be causing the problem. Try logging in with a test account and working for a while, to see if it's related to some program you're running in your account. Look in `/var/log/kern.log` for suspicious messages (I don't know what the messages would look like; normally this file gets a lot of messages at boot time and not many afterwards, you may want to post the part of the file after the end of the boot process so that someone can look at it).

When the problem occurs, run `xev` and observe the events sent by the mouse. Clicking on a button in the `xev` window should send a `ButtonPress` event followed by a `ButtonRelease`. Pressing a key should send `KeyPress` followed by `KeyRelease`. The `state` value should always be `0x0` when you don't have a modifier or button pressed. If you always see `0x400`, it means that your system is specifically dropping right mouse button releases. If you sometimes see `0x100` or `0x200` when the problem occurs, it means your system is dropping left and middle releases too.

Comment: Not sure what is meant by "you may want to part of the file". This may be a typo.

Comment: @FaheemMitha [status-completed]

Comment: @Gilles - this is exactly what was happening. Pretty sure its a hardware issue Disabling the touchpad on the netbook has solved the problem. Looks like the right click key is jammed or at least it thinks its jammed.